# Centos 6 /usr/sbin/sendmail - how to send email with subject?

Tags: shell, sendmail, centos6, postfix-mta

Trying to send an email from shell (Centos 6) using one line command, but subject is empty

```
echo 'body' | /usr/sbin/sendmail x@gmail.com Subject:"Test Send Mail"
```

Spent hours trying googling and find an answer how to send email  using "/usr/sbin/sendmail" with subject, but no matter what I try, subject is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(echo "Subject: Test"; echo; echo 'body')|/usr/sbin/sendmail -i x@gmail.com`

Or cleaner script version

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/sbin/sendmail -i x@gmail.com <<END
Subject: Test

body
END
```

**WARNINGS**:

1. Non US-ASCII characters require special encoding in headers and custom headers when included in body.
2. Keep subject (header) in single text line
   [header continuation lines must start with space or tab]
3. Sendmail breaks too long text lines (990 bytes)

Comment: Thank you, that worked! what is the 2nd empty echo for?

Comment: Because you have to feed in a valid RFC5322 message on standard input and that's how the headers are separated from the body in this format.

Comment: How Do I set "From" address in the one line version? thanks in advance

Comment: I got it. (echo "Subject: Test"; echo "From: x@gmail.com"; echo 'body')|/usr/sbin/sendmail -i x@gmail.com

Comment: How to add attachment ?

Comment: @HariomSingh Usually it is easier to use higher level tools (e.g. `mail` command) except trivial cases e.g. html **only** body.